# Deve-se redimensionar uma imagem no navegador?

Tags: css, html5, css3, imagem, layout-responsivo

Já li em alguns lugares que não devemos redimensionar as imagens que pedimos do servidor no navegador. Mas vi recentemente que é bom termos uma imagem grande com uma qualidade baixa pra que quando essas imagens sejam baixadas em uma tela de retina elas fiquem com uma qualidade razoável.

Mas preciso de uma imagem pequena para colocar na minha. Então a minha pergunta é: Como faço? Pego uma imagem grande e redimensiono ela no meu CSS, ou pego uma imagem do tamanho exato que preciso?

Comment: O ideal seria mandares do servidor uma imagem com o tamnho exato, para o browser (navegador) não estar a fazer download de mais recursos (imagem maior = mais pesada) do que realmente vai precisar. tens aqui uma boa ferramenta para otimizar imagens, não tem diretamente a haver com o tamanho mas é útil, eu costumo usar isso

Comment: @Miguel qual ferramenta?

Comment: Opps, lol @JorgeB. esqueci-me de colocar o link: https://kraken.io/web-interface

Answer (score -1):

Não deve. Mas tem casos e casos em que você pode redimensionar com moderação.

Você não pode pegar uma imagem 2000x2000 e adequar ela no HTML para 300x200. Primeiro, por conta da proporção que será modificada. Para diminuir ela, você pode utilizar um sistema para gerenciar thumbnails (ex: [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/)).

Porém, mesmo assim às vezes não é suficiente.

Por exemplo, um site responsivo, onde a mesma imagem aparece em uma coluna de 720px e 320px. Você pode usar o Intervention para gerar a imagem em 720px e, caso use Bootstrap, usar uma classe chamada "img-responsive", que adapta a largura de acordo com o container pai.

Em ambos casos, ainda se possível, utilize otimizadores de imagens como o que o @JorgeB. citou. Eu, pessoalmente utilizo um software chamado [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com), que é free. Ele dá uma otimizada no arquivo sem perda de qualidade.